# Javascript button not responding when clicked

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am attempting to use [listjs](http://listjs.com) in a django project i am making. But even when running a snippet taken from the documentation, django refused to run it properly. Take this [pen](https://codepen.io/javve/pen/zpuKF) for example. I copy this and put it in my `html` template. The template now has the following

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);
    </script>

<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>

  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonny Stromberg</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonas Arnklint</h3>
      <p class="born">1985</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Martina Elm</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</h3>
      <p class="born">1983</p>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Result is the page loads fine with no errors in the console but the button or the search do not work at all. I think it is something obvious i am missing here but cant seem to track it.

Comment: Are the tags right for this question?

Comment: @Sreeram i believe so, you think i should add something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading scripts at the end of your snippet. `listjs` library is expecting DOM to be loaded before you can create new `List`.

```
<div id="users">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
    Sort by name
  </button>

  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonny Stromberg</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Jonas Arnklint</h3>
      <p class="born">1985</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Martina Elm</h3>
      <p class="born">1986</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="name">Gustaf Lindqvist</h3>
      <p class="born">1983</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'name', 'born' ]
};

var userList = new List('users', options);

</script>
```